# RExcel Error: There seems to be no R process connected to Excel

Tags: r, excel, rexcel

Today when I run "start R" from `RExcel` addin menu in Excel, I get the error messages:

`There seems to be no R process connected to Excel`

But it is OK before today, and also work now when setting the system time to the date before today, such as 2015/12/30.

Environment:
1. `Windows 7 64bit`, `Excel 2010`
2. `R 3.1.1` or `R 3.1.3`
3. `RExcel 3.2.15`, `statconnDCOM3.6-0B2_Noncommercial`

What is the issue?  And how can I do?

Answer (score 6):

To put you out of your misery, it seems it is a problem with the license embedded in the statconn program/installer. The mailing list suggest a new version will be out in a few days. It failed on me suddenly too!

Cheers
Iain

On Thu, Dec 31, 2015 at 5:03 PM, Thomas Baier  wrote:

> Hi Philipp & Kunal,
>
> this seems to be a problem with statconnDCOM for the Home&Student
>   Version. Will upload a fix within the next days.
>
> Sorry for the inconveniences.
>
> Best regards,
>   Thomas
>
> Am 31.12.2015 um 09:37 schrieb Philipp Guggenberger:
>
> > Hello Kunal,
> >
> > same problem here. It seems, that the statconn license has been expired.
> >     But on the statconn website is no newer license file to download. If you
> >     set the date of your PC back to e.g. 12/30 the add-in works fine.
> >
> > Regards
> >
> > Philipp
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Rcom-l mailing list
> >     Rcom-l at lists.univie.ac.at
> >     https://lists.univie.ac.at/mailman/listinfo/rcom-l
>
> --
>   Thomas Baier 
>   http://www.statconn.com/
>
> ---

Comment: There should be an updated version available now on the download site that works past 30th Dec 2015.

http://rcom.univie.ac.at/